# Sending callback variables from Express get method to forked process in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to send the callback variables from app.get() to a forked process but when I do this I'm getting the following error:

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

The purpose of this is so that I can have a main node web server and drop new applications into the server without having to recreate a new server. Here's some abbreviated code that's causing the issue:

```
app.get('/apps/*', function(req, res) {

    req.session.myPath = req.route.params;
    var progname = new RegExp("(.*?)\\/", "g").exec(req.session.myPath[0])[1];

    if (applications.indexOf(progname) != -1) {
        var appInstance = cp.fork('./apps/'+progname+'/main.js');
        appInstance.send({'_req':req,'_res':res});  <-- Error here
    }

});
```

Is there a way to pass these variables to the forked main.js  process to allow that process to handle the page request rather than the traditional way of including it in the app.get callback function?,

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to pass these variables to the forked main.js process to allow that process to handle the page request rather than the traditional way of including it in the app.get callback function?

Not if it's a child process. These are process-specific resources so you can't pass them to a different process. However, express has the notion of mounting sub applications, so you could implement a bunch of separate express apps and then mount them all in a contain application. Otherwise your sub-apps will need to provide an HTTP interface you could proxy to, but that would be done via HTTP not by trying to directly serialize the `req` and `res` objects to JSON data.